# E(|X|) for a normal r.v

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

I struggle with absolute value. Here I need to find $\mathbb{E}[X^4]$ and $\mathbb{E}[|X|]$ knowing that $X$ is a normally distributed random variable with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$.

I know the pdf of the normal r.v. and the way to compute $\mathbb{E}[X^4]$:

$$\mathbb{E}[X^4]=\int x^4 f_X(x) dx$$

But how should I handle the absolute sign when I compute:

$$\int \mid x \mid f_X(x) dx $$

I understand I should divide the integral into the part from $-\infty$ to $0$ and 0 to $\infty$ and take that into account, but how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x|f_X(x)\,dx=
-\int_{-\infty}^0xf(x)\,dx+\int_0^{+\infty}xf(x)\,dx$$
this follows simply by [definition of the absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties).

Comment: Exactly the little hint I needed. Simple but extremely helpful. Thanks !

Comment: @endlessend2525 you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Another way**

Set $Y=|X|$ we have
\begin{align*}
G_Y(y)&=\mathbb{P}(Y\le y)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(\,|X|\le y\,)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(-y\le X\le y)\\
&=F_X(y)-F_X(-y)
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$g_Y(y)=f_X(y)+f_X(-y)$$
In other words
\begin{align*}
g_Y(y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac 12 y^2}\, &,\,y>0\\
0 &,\text{o.w}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
thus

$$\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-\frac 12 y^2}dy$$

Comment: Why stop without computing the last integral?

Comment: Set $y^2=u$ . we have $2ydy=du$

Comment: I know, thanks, the mistake not included (you forgot a factor 2)... The point is that this should be in the answer.